# Error: object and replacement value have different dimensions

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

[enter image description here][1]I am a student who is learning how to do microarray analysis. I ran into the following error and was hoping someone has guidance on how to troubleshoot the issue. Thank you.
Update: I was trying to post a picture but it wouldn't let me because my reputation value is low.

```
exprs(my.rma) <- exprs(my.rma)[present >= [enter image description here][2]4,]
Error in .validate_assayDataElementReplace(obj, value) : 
 object and replacement value have different dimensions
```

Comment: Can you provide your data using `dput` function? dput(your data)

Comment: `exprs` is not a base R function. Please provide the name of the package the function belongs to. Also please include a minimal sample data set and an explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am not sure what `my.rma` is but I guess if you change the code to `exprs(my.rma) <- exprs(my.rma)[which(present >= 4),]`, it will work

Comment: Hi, my rma  is a large expressionset (2.3 MB). The function derives from affymatrix. I am trying  remove t the probesets that correspond to genes that are not expressed.

Comment: rma features the following:                                                                                                     Name: my.rma                                                                                                                       Type: S4[31099X16]( BioExpressionset)                                                                             Value:  s4 object class Expressionset